# Немецкий и германский

Tags: лексика

Нормативно ли сочетание "германский язык", когда говорят о немецком?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Государственный язык Германии — немецкий.

Германские языки — группа родственных языков, одна из ветвей индоевропейской семьи языков. Немецкий язык входит в группу германский языков. Вы можете о немецком языке сказать «германский», если хотите подчеркнуть именно его принадлежность к германской группе языков. А если вы хотите сказать, например, что вы знаете, изучаете немецкий язык (не английский, не французский), то только так — «немецкий».

Answer (score 5):

Сегодня по отношению к немцам и Германии употребляются прилагательные немецкий и германский. Прилагательное германский в значении "немецкий" дается многими словарями как устарелое (например: С. И. Ожегов и Н. Ю. Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка. 4-е изд., М., 1997). Однако в настоящее время сфера употребления прилагательного германский расширяется, во многом благодаря заботе германской стороны (например, слово германский почти исключительно употребляется на сайте Посольства Германии в Российской Федерации). Вот рекомендация сотрудников посольства: "Ответ короткий: немецкий - это язык, продукт, человек и т. п., всё что связано с национальностью; германский - это гимн, флаг, парламент и т. д., т. е. всё, что связано с государственностью. Похоже на: русский язык, литература, жена и российский герб, гимн, президент".