Лени Рифеншталь — немецкая кинорежиссёр и фотограф?

Лени Рифеншталь —  немецкая кинорежиссёр и фотограф?


Аньес Варда (30 мая 1928 — 29 марта 2019) — французский кинорежиссёр,
сценаристка и фотограф. Википедия...

Правильно "немецкий кинорежиссёр" конечно. Либо немецкая кинорежиссерка?
Да нет конечно! Немецкий кинорежиссёр, сценарист - правильно, независимо от пола, потому что это не пол, а род.

...Однако, несмотря на свободное образование подобных названий в форме
женского рода, они используются не во всех стилях речи. Так, в
официально-деловом стиле предпочтительно сохранять форму мужского
рода, когда речь идет о номенклатурном наименовании должности; ср. в
документе-справке: «А. В. Петрова работает лаборантом на кафедре
физики» (в обиходной речи – лаборантка Петрова); «Л. И. Николаева
является преподавателем английского языка» (в обиходной речи –
преподавательница Николаева). Ср. бытовое: заведующая отделом Никитина
и официальное: управляющий трестом Никитина. Грамота.ру

Согласование определений там же, необособленное определение:
а) необособленное определение ставится в форме мужского рода (даже при наличии в предложении собственного имени): В журнале «Знамя» появился новый автор Н. Петрова. Уже известный читателям автор Н. Петрова предложила новую статью.
б)  обособленное определение ставится в форме женского рода, если оно стоит после собственного имени: Автор Н. Петрова, уже известная читателям, предложила новую статью.
в) определение-причастие ставится в форме женского рода независимо от порядка слов: Предложившая новую статью автор Н. Петрова уже известна читателям. Автор Н. Петрова, предложившая новую статью, уже известна читателям.

Голос от  меня, хороший у вас материал по ссылке.

@Sharon могут же, когда хотят. А на педивикии не хотят, ошибки делать хотят, задача такая. Вот вам и бесплатный сыр.

@Sharon также рекомендую сравнить уровень когнитивного диссонанса: "Адольф Гитлер (20 апреля 1889 — 30 апреля 1945) — германский политический и государственный деятель, диктатор, глава и главный идеолог Национал-социалистической немецкой рабочей партии (НСДАП) и германского государства в период нацизма (1933–1945)." педивикия.

"ГИ́ТЛЕР, Хитлер (Hitler) Адольф (20.4.1889, Браунау, Австро-Венгрия – 30.4.1945, Берлин), глава герм. гос-ва в период нацистской диктатуры (1933–45), гл. воен. преступник." Большая Российская Энциклопедия "старая".

"Ги́тлер Адо́льф, Адольф Хитлер (Adolf Hitler) (20.4.1889, Браунау, Австро-Венгрия, ныне Браунау-ам-Инн, Австрия – 30.4.1945, Берлин), германский политический и государственный деятель, диктатор, глава и главный идеолог Национал-социалистической немецкой рабочей партии (НСДАП) и германского государства в период нацизма (1933–1945). На Нюрнбергских процессах 1945–1949 гг. признан главным военным преступником." То же самое "новая". Регалий прибавилось и стал "германцем". Вообще, это два разных народа, немцы и германцы?) Немцы "хорошие", германцы "плохие"?

"Герхард Шрёдер (род. 7 апреля 1944, Моссенберг-Вёрен, Германия) — немецкий государственный деятель и политик." - ахаха, ну вы поняли...

И даже больше: "Шрёдер Ге́рхард, Герхард Фриц Курт Шрёдер (Gerhard Fritz Kurt Schröder) (род. 7.4.1944, Моссенберг, земля Северный Рейн-Вестфалия), германский государственный и политический деятель, топ-менеджер; иностранный член РАН (2008). В 1958–1961 гг. находился в ученичестве в магазине, получив в итоге образование специалиста по экономике розничной торговли, окончил юридический факультет Гёттингенского университета (1971)." - .."новая".

На форуме обсуждалось  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/Немецкий-и-германский У нас тоже проблема: русский – российский.

русский-российский понятно в целом, русский - это прилагательное, культура, народ, а российский - это принадлежность государству РФ, а немцы, кроме нас, их никто не называет.

Понятно, да не совсем. Вот наш любознательный народ интересуется: какая разница межу русской горчицей и российской (есть такие названия). Он вообще удивительный, наш народ).  Даже названия у нас не такие, как у всех.

@Sharon русскый язык, очен сложны язык. Слова "вилька" и "тарелька" пишуца бэз мягкого знака, а слова шмел и мол с мягким знаком! Дэти, этого нэльзя объясныть, это надо запомныть!

Да уж, умом Россию не понять, и с общим аршином лучше не подходить)
